# percentage symbol to decimal numbers in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Using .net

To add a $ symbol for numbers I did
Texbox1.Text.Format = "C"

How to add % symbol at the end of each integer to represent a string in textbox.

Comment: What framework are you using? That's not valid code for WinForms/WPF.

Comment: Sure it is.  C is a valid format specifier.  Check the link posted by dtb.

Comment: "C" is the standard Currency ("C") Format Specifier, so I'm guessing he's looking for a format specifier that deals with percent values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double number = 1.2;
lbl.Text = number.ToString("P");
```

Produces: 120.00%

```
double number = 0.12;
lbl.Text = number.ToString("P");
```

Produces: 12.00%

So if you have a percentage already:

```
double number = 12;
lbl.Text = (number / 100).ToString("P");
```

Produces: 12.00%

Answer (score 6):

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx); in particular: the [Percent ("P") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#PFormatString).